# Age of hard drive via software tool on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, raid5

I an running Intel Raid 5 on Windows 7, and one of my hard drives is reporting an error. This is the second time I've had a hard drive error, and last time I replaced the problem drive.

Now I've had an error again, but I can't remember which drive I replaced. It looks like it might be the new drive that has failed.

Is there a way to check the manufacture date of a hard drive without opening the computer case and pulling out the drive?

EDIT:

Maybe the serial number holds the key.

Serial: WD-WCAW34588468

Model: WDC WD1002FAEX-00Y9A0

Firmware: 05.01D05

I have two WD drives and one Seagate in the Raid. Last time I replaced a WD drive, but they now have the same firmware and model number. So I can't tell which one is newer.

EDIT:

If it turns out that the failed drive is again on the same port. Would this indicate a problem with that specific port?

Comment: Not getting the info from Windows, but you can pop that serial into [WDC's Warranty Check](https://westerndigital.secure.force.com/WarrantyCheck?lang=en) and find out when it was sold (warranty expiration less the warranty period).

Comment: Probably is a failed cable or controller card... Might want to install [smartmontools](http://sourceforge.net/projects/smartmontools/) to figure out what the drive thinks is happening (might not work with your RAID card).

Comment: @ChrisS thank you! that was the trick. It is the new drive reporting the problem. I will try replacing the cable as well (I have dozens of them around here) and I'll give that tool a try. Post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it ;)

Answer (score 2):

Open up an elevate powershell command prompt and do the following

gwmi win32_diskdrive | ft FirmwareRevision

Comment: Mine returns a big fat blank. =]

Comment: `gwmi win32_diskdrive` shows the RAID drive, but not the drives that make up the rain. No firmware details either.

Comment: realized this is not much use in this case!

Comment: not sure why I'm being upvoted since it didn't answer a darn thing!

Comment: once again elevate a ps sessions then run the following "gwmi -namespace "root" -class "__Namespace" | Select Name" you may see a namespace that refers to your raid controller then run "gwmi -namespace "root\raidcontrollernamespace" -list". Now sometimes if there is an associated namespace you can dig deeper into the details of all the devices within the raid subsystems..